# On emitting an object, all items of object getting pushed in all arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Extremely sorry for a confusing title, but I don't know how to word it better. So I have two Vue components which are exchanging some data. Here is my parent component

```
<template>
  <dashboard-detail-form @submit-query="updatePaymentEntry"
  ref="dashDetailForm"></dashboard-detail-form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import DashboardDetailForm from './DashboardDetailForm'

export default {
  components: {
    DashboardDetailForm
  },
  name: 'DashboardDetailPost',
  props: {
    paymentEntry: Object
  },
  methods: {
    updatePaymentEntry (data) {
      this.paymentEntry.amountRecievedParentArray[this.paymentEntry.amountRecievedParentArray.length] = data.amountRecievedParent
      this.paymentEntry.paymentModeParentArray[this.paymentEntry.paymentModeParentArray.length] = data.paymentModeParent
      this.paymentEntry.datePaymentParentArray[this.paymentEntry.datePaymentParentArray.length] = data.datePaymentParent
      this.paymentEntry.amountPaidTutorArray[this.paymentEntry.amountPaidTutorArray.length] = data.amountPaidTutor
      this.paymentEntry.paymentModeTutorArray[this.paymentEntry.paymentModeTutorArray.length] = data.paymentModeTutor
      this.paymentEntry.datePaymentTutorArray[this.paymentEntry.datePaymentTutorArray.length] = data.datePaymentTutor
      this.addPaymentEntry();
    },
    addPaymentEntry () {
      axios({
        method: 'put',
        url: this.paymentEntry.url,
        data: {
          amount_recieved_parent: this.paymentEntry.amountRecievedParentArray,
          payment_mode_parent: this.paymentEntry.paymentModeParentArray,
          date_payment_parent: this.paymentEntry.datePaymentParentArray,
          amount_payed_tutor: this.paymentEntry.amountPaidTutorArray,
          payment_mode_tutor: this.paymentEntry.paymentModeTutorArray,
          date_payment_tutor: this.paymentEntry.datePaymentTutorArray
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.$refs.dashDetailForm.resetForm()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the child component

```
export default {
  components: {
    FormDropdown,
    FormInput
  },
  name: 'DashboardDetailForm',
  props: {
    editDetailForm: Object
  },
  data () {
    return {
      showForm: false,
      form: {
        amountRecievedParent: null,
        paymentModeParent: '',
        datePaymentParent: '',
        amountPaidTutor: null,
        paymentModeTutor: '',
        datePaymentTutor: ''
      },
      paymentModeArray: [
        { value: "cash", text: "Cash" },
        { value: "paytm", text: "PayTM" },
        { value: "bank seth", text: "Bank Seth" },
        { value: "bank anuj", text: "Bank Anuj" },
        { value: "kotak", text: "Kotak" }
      ]
    }
  },
  created () {
    if (typeof this.editDetailForm !== "undefined") {
      this.form.amountRecievedParent = this.editDetailForm.amountRecievedParent
      this.form.paymentModeParent = this.editDetailForm.paymentModeParent
      this.form.datePaymentParent = this.editDetailForm.datePaymentParent
      this.form.amountPaidTutor = this.editDetailForm.amountPaidTutor
      this.form.paymentModeTutor = this.editDetailForm.paymentModeTutor
      this.form.datePaymentTutor = this.editDetailForm.datePaymentTutor
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formToggle () {
      this.showForm = !this.showForm
    },
    resetDetailForm () {
      this.form.amountRecievedParent = null,
      this.form.paymentModeParent = '',
      this.form.datePaymentParent = '',
      this.form.amountPaidTutor = null,
      this.form.paymentModeTutor = '',
      this.form.datePaymentParent = ''
    },
    validateBeforeSubmit () {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
        if(!this.errors.any()) {
          this.$emit('submit-query', this.form)
          this.formToggle()
        }
      })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Now I am getting correct values in the form property of my child component. Now when I click the button to call validateBeforeSubmit() function, it emits the form object to the parent component which listens to it and call updatePaymentEntry method. This is where problem starts. Now each of the property of paymentEntry object have six items i.e. all the values that were in form object of child component are getting pushed in each of the paymentEntry's property of parent component. I don't understand how is this happening. In my earlier tries I was using .push() command to appending items to array but got the same bug.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone explain me?

EDIT: parent of parent component as requested

```
<template>
  <div id="dash-detail">
    <dashboard-detail-post
    :paymentEntry="paymentEntryComputed"></dashboard-detail-post>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sr.No.</th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Mode of Payment</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template v-if="entry.amount_recieved_parent !== 0 || entry.amount_payed_tutor !== 0">
          <template v-for="(el, index) in entry.amount_recieved_parent">
            <tr :key="index">
              <th rowspan="2">{{ index }}</th>
              <th>From Parents</th>
              <th>{{ entry.amount_recieved_parent[index] }}</th>
              <th>{{ entry.payment_mode_parent[index] }}</th>
              <th>{{ entry.date_payment_parent[index] }}</th>
              <th rowspan="2">
                <dashboard-detail-edit :paymentEntry="entry"
                :paymentIndex="index"></dashboard-detail-edit>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr :key="index">
              <th>To Tutor</th>
              <th>{{ entry.amount_payed_tutor[index] }}</th>
              <th>{{ entry.payment_mode_tutor[index] }}</th>
              <th>{{ entry.date_payment_tutor[index] }}</th>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import DashboardDetailEdit from './DashboardDetailEdit'
import DashboardDetailPost from './DashboardDetailPost'

export default {
  name: 'DashboardDetail',
  components: {
    DashboardDetailEdit,
    DashboardDetailPost
  },
  data () {
    return {
      entry: {},
      paymentEntry: {
        url: '',
        amountRecievedParentArray: [],
        paymentModeParentArray: [],
        datePaymentParentArray: [],
        amountPaidTutorArray: [],
        paymentModeTutorArray: [],
        datePaymentTutorArray: []
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getEntry() {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/' + this.$route.params.id + '/'
      }).then(response => this.entry = response.data);
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getEntry()
  },
  computed: {
    paymentEntryComputed: function () {
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("amount_recieved_parent") && this.entry.amount_recieved_parent !== null)
        this.paymentEntry.amountRecievedParentArray = this.entry.amount_recieved_parent
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("payment_mode_parent") && this.entry.payment_mode_parent !== null)
        this.paymentEntry.paymentModeParentArray = this.entry.payment_mode_parent
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("date_payment_parent") && this.entry.date_payment_parent !== null)
        this.paymentEntry.datePaymentParentArray = this.entry.date_payment_parent
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("amount_payed_tutor") && this.entry.amount_payed_tutor !== null)
        this.paymentEntry.amountPaidTutorArray = this.entry.amount_payed_tutor
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("payment_mode_tutor") && this.entry.payment_mode_tutor !== null)
        this.paymentEntry.paymentModeTutorArray = this.entry.payment_mode_tutor
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("date_payment_tutor") && this.entry.date_payment_tutor !== null)
        this.paymentEntry.datePaymentTutorArray = this.entry.date_payment_tutor
      if (this.entry !== null && this.entry.hasOwnProperty("url"))
        this.paymentEntry.url = this.entry.url
      return this.paymentEntry
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you provide the parent component of the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't directly manipulate a property in a component.

It seems your `paymentEntry` is passed to the parent as a property. Either hold a local copy, manipulate that and then update or look into the `.sync` modifier for properties (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) if you're sure this is what you want to do.

Also `push` was the right way to go.

Comment: Help me understand this, you want me to make a copy of paymentEntry Object in my parent component, then manipulate it and pass the local copy data to axios, right? There is one more problem I'm facing is that the "grandParent Component's" paymentEntry object is automatically updated without actually emitting it from parent component, is it because I'm manipulating paymentEntry object itself in parent component?

Comment: It seems you need to better understand the way Vue orchestrates dataflow between components. I suggest you read up on this, the short version is though: data is passed down from parent to child via properties (and should usually be considered immutable within the child context). Events flow up from child to parent and can trigger data updates etc.. You should never directly manipulate a data object which is passed in as a property (think of it as the ownership of that data lies by the parent, only the parent should be allowed to change it).